# Numerical troubles in LP

Tags: optimization, scip

I have implemented a benders decomposition algorithm for solving a large scale linear program. But, I get this error after a few rounds of cuts (for the master problem). I have tried changing the LP solver to gurobi, and still seem to face the same problem. I had changed the feasibility tolerance to `1e-9`, so that the cut which I have added is satisfied. Is it possible that this might be playing a role in these numerical issues?

```
[solve.c:3905] ERROR: (node 1) unresolved numerical troubles in LP 2 cannot be dealt with
[solve.c:4190] ERROR: Error <-6> in function call
[solve.c:4984] ERROR: Error <-6> in function call
[scip_solve.c:2748] ERROR: Error <-6> in function call
```

Comment: Tightening the tolerances can most definitely have that effect. Your reasoning does not really make sense though. If your cut is not satisfied at 1e-6 it ist most certainly also not satisifed at 1e-9. Did you mean violated?

Comment: Thanks! When the tolerance was at the default value, adding the cut won't cutoff the solution (even though the cut was violated), and this would result in an infinite loop. Hence, I thought that tightening the tolerances may be a good idea to combat this, and force the solver to satisfy the cut. This worked for smaller instances, but for larger instances, the code running into numerical issues.